# Error after updating my hibernate from 3 to 4

Tags: hibernate, maven, spring-mvc, pom.xml

In the attempt to add Hibernate Search feature to my existing project, I edited my pom.xml file, specifically changed hibernate version from 3 to 4. And the following error arised

```
ERROR: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
```

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'articleDaoImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory air.pedagog.minbari.dao.ArticleDaoImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/data.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.addAnnotatedClass(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/hibernate/cfg/Configuration;

this is my data.xml for sessionFactory and TransactionManager

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<!-- Менеджер транзакций -->
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
</bean>

<!-- Настройки бина dataSource будем хранить в отдельном файле -->
<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
    p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />

<!-- Непосредственно бин dataSource -->
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
    p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}" 
    p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}"
    p:username="${jdbc.username}" 
    p:password="${jdbc.password}" />

<!-- Настройки фабрики сессий Хибернейта -->
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="air.pedagog.minbari.domain" />

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

HERE is my troublemaking pom.xml file

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>air.pedagog</groupId>
<artifactId>minbari</artifactId>
<name>pedagogMinbari</name>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
<properties>
    <java-version>1.6</java-version>
    <org.springframework-version>3.2.8.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
    <spring.security.version>3.2.3.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
    <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
    <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
             </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Postgres -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.1-901.jdbc4</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Hibernate -->
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
     <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
     <version>4.2.15.Final</version>
  </dependency> 
  <dependency>
 <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
 <artifactId>hibernate-search-engine</artifactId>
 <version>4.3.0.Final</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
 <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
 <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
 <version>4.3.0.Final</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
     <groupId>javassist</groupId>
     <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
     <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
     <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
     <version>3.1.4.GA</version>
  </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>       
    <!-- AspectJ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
    </dependency>   

    <!-- Logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.15</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- @Inject -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Dependencies for image load/retrieve-->        
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>20030825.184428</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Apache Commons-Codec -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.5</version>
    </dependency>
            <!-- Spring Security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring Security JSP Taglib -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

I looked through all similar problems (may by i missed some) in stackoverflow, through the way to here i solved some related problems like right classes for 4 when switching from 3. I am only 6 month in spring mvc, so Any assist would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow the steps below:

1.Please run a maven dependancy tree command below:

```
mvn:dependency:tree
```

2. Make sure that you dont have more than 1 Spring and 1 Hibernate release versions.

Comment: I did all steps. Maven builds successed but the problem remains.

Comment: I guess there is more than 1 hibernate release jar in the classpath. You are getting this issue since you have multiple versions of Hibernate Dependency in your classpath. Please see post below :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29092118/spring-3-hibernate-4-c3p0-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-springframework

Comment: thank you! you were right, i followed the steps and found 2 javassist(one was in hibernate core which then i excluded). you saved my day

Answer (score 0):

The error is that you have incompatible versions in your stack - i.e. something is expecting the older version of hibernate (most likely the version of Spring you are using).

If you really need to upgrade your Hibernate then you will need to upgrade these too.  Find compatible versions via [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io/)